# Java StackOverflow due to infinite initializations

Tags: java, sdk, lazy-initialization

I'm building an SDK for my APIs, in which there are two modules consider Class A and Class B.

```
public class A{
    public final B = new B();
    public final A = new A();
    public String nameOfA;
}

public class B{
    public final A = new A();
    public final B = new B();
    public String nameOfB;
}
```

There are fields inside each module that refers to other modules and also themselves. The end-users using the SDK should be able to do something like A.B.A.nameOfA, B.A.nameOfA, etc.
But these module classes are generated dynamically by a tool. This causes the StackOverFlow Error.
Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Those classes in the form you have them can never be instantiated.  If your tool is generating these, you need to use a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

Classic infinite recursion.
What you want to do is logically not possible and doesn't make any sense at all. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?